# ASP MVC5, Windows server 2012 and IIS 8.5: how improve performance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 r2 and an asp mvc 5 web app published on iis 8.5.
When i navigate in the website, the first time i load a new page, the loading time is very big (i.e: 30 sec for 340k). Instead if i refresh the same page, the loading time is very fast (but i think is due to the cache).

How can i improve the loading time of every page? There are some tricks?

In IIS 8.5 i have set the DefaultApplicationPool to:[image]

and when i publish the asp mvc 5 from visual studio i don't check any options (ie: Remove additional files at destination, Precompile during publishing, Exclude files from the App_Data folder)

When i try on the development machine (visual studio and iis express) the loading page is very fast

Comment: You are mixing up the site's startup time (the 30 secs) with the actual page's load time. There is no caching involved unless you specified it. If you want to reduce startup time, configure precompilation. You may be able to do *less* stuff at startup too. Eg instead of laoding all lookup data at App_Start, load only the most useful etc

Comment: no...i have noticed that the site is slow only on the first access of every page. After, every user that visit the same page, experience a fast page loading time

Comment: What is going on in each page then? Did you try a tool like Glimpse to see what is actually going on? Did you try Visual Studio Profiler to see what gets called? It's impossible to advice how to optimize a page without any idea what that page does

Comment: My guess is that the first time the loading takes a while because the pages are getting compiled for the first time.